# Multiple ForeignKey to the same field in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I can't add two foreign key constraints to the same field?

I am not 100% sure about the relationship, so I have included the tables. Hope it can help others with learning Django as well:
**Transaction**

```
+----------+-----+---------------------+
|   guid   | plu |      datetime       |
+----------+-----+---------------------+
| 00003516 |   1 | 2015-09-22 12:11:12 |
| 0000386a |   2 | 2015-02-22 12:11:10 |
| 0000c59d |   2 | 2015-03-22 12:11:10 |
| 0000f03f |   3 | 2015-01-22 12:12:12 |
+----------+-----+---------------------+
```

**Plu**

```
+-----+------+
| plu | name |
+-----+------+
|   1 | aaa  |
|   2 | bbb  |
|   3 | ccc  |
+-----+------+
```

**Finance**

```
+-----+------------+------------+-------+
| plu |    from    |     to     | price |
+-----+------------+------------+-------+
|   1 | 2013-01-22 | 2015-01-23 |    10 |
|   1 | 2015-01-23 | 2015-02-29 |    20 |
|   2 | 2013-01-22 | 2015-01-22 |    10 |
|   3 | 2013-01-22 | 2015-01-22 |    30 |
+-----+------------+------------+-------+
```

Based on this I have created the following models:
**Finance**

```
class Finance(models.Model):
    guid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    from = models.DateField()
    to = models.DateField()
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
```

**PLU**

```
class Plu(models.Model):
    plu = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
```

**Transaction**

```
class Transaction(models.Model):
    guid = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=38)
    plu = models.ForeignKey(Plu, db_column='plu')
    finance = models.ForeignKey(Finance, db_column='plu')
    datetime = models.DateTimeField()
```

When I try to run this i get the following error - what to do?:

```
app.Transaction: (models.E007) Field 'finance' has column name 'plu' that is used by another field.
    HINT: Specify a 'db_column' for the field.
```

Comment: I'm running into the exact same issue, but I want to clarify, that the constraint is the physical database column the relationship is derived from must be the same? I have a read-only database, and I cannot change `db_column` to something else, because then the relationship would break.

Answer (score 1):

You've copy and pasted and included the same db_column name, you need to change it

```
finance = models.ForeignKey(Finance, db_column='finance')
```

Note: You don't actually need the db_column specified at all since you're just setting it to the name of the field anyway

```
finance = models.ForeignKey(Finance)
```

Comment: When I implement the suggested change I get the following error: `(1054, "Unknown column 'Transaction.finance_id' in 'field list'")`. I assume db_column='plu' is needed since it is the underlying field to reference?

Comment: @DauleDK - Thats probably because you need to run `makemigrations/migrate`, although that is a separate issue

Comment: I don't understand why it is a separate issue. The question is how to define 2 relationships on the same field, not creating a new field through a migration?